# Is it ok to keep rechargeable batteries in an unplugged charger?

Tags: batteries

Is it ok to keep rechargeable batteries in an unplugged charger considering possibility of discharging the batteries via the charger's circuitry, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd expect it to be OK in many cases - BUT no guarantees as it depends on the charger designer. If the charger was powered you'd hope most designers would place the cell in a neutral mode. You'd hope. Unpowered it is not hard to draw almost zero current, should the designer care and 'know their stuff'.

**An experiment:**

Your question is easily answered in a specific case by an experiment.

Place a battery in the unplugged charger with a small piece of paper between battery +ve nipple and +ve charger electrode so that the battery is isolated by the paper.
Set a multimeter to lowest current range and connect probes between charger +ve and battery +ve.
A well designed charger should produce at most < 100 uA and it would be easy to get this < 10 uA and not hard at all to get < or << 1 uA.

If smoke comes out of the meter while performing this test the charger is (or was) of an inferior design.

Lacking a low enough range ammeter, use a voltmeter - play to see what range gves highest reading. Now try eg a 1 megohm and 10 megohm resistor in series with bttery and meter and see how they compare.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the charger circuit and on the battery type really. Usually there will be quiescent currents and a complete discharge of the reachargeable batteries may damage the battery due to remaining in the discharged state (for further details look into the chemical reactions). If you intend to store the batteries for a long period of time it is advisable to charge them from time to time. 
If you refer to multi-cell batteries another effect called cell reversal might occur which happens simply because one cell discharges faster than the others and changes polarity.

So to answer the question: Do not leave rechargeable batteries discharging for long periods of time regardless of the charger altough the charger might accelerate the process.